# Why can't I open my List in Designer after Domain move?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

We moved our Content DB to a new server in a new forest in a new domain.  I can access the List using Internet Explorer, but when I click on the list in Designer I see the following error:

[image]

This ONLY happens for Lists that have Workflows on them.  I don't mind killing and rebuilding the workflows, but see my associated question on the problem I'm encountering trying to delete the workflows.  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73670/how-to-workaround-workflow-checked-out-by-non-existent-account

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also was because my domain account had been deleted (the original one used to create the workflows).  Republishing the Global workflows, then republishing the List workflows, allowed me to get into the lists and also use the workflows again.